# angular ui grid how to display html in the grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm trying to display html in the grid
looking at

[Add html link in anyone of ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310007/add-html-link-in-anyone-of-ng-grid)

I ended up with

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
            app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.myData = [
                        {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                        {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                        {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                        {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                        {name: "Enos", age: 34}
                    ];
                $scope.gridOptions = { 
                    data: 'myData',
                    columnDefs: [
                        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
                        {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}, 
                        {field: 'remove', displayName:'', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a href="{{row.getProperty(age)}}">Visible text</a></div>'}
                    ]
                };
            });
```

but it doesn't work (the href attribute is empty)
so what's the right way ?
Bye

Comment: I'm wondering why -1 ! the other reply doesn't work !

Comment: I always use `ng-href` in place of `href` if there is angular in the URL...[see the ngHref doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in href

`{{row.getProperty(\'age\')}}`

Comment: It works like a charme :) thanks with just a little escape row.getProperty(\'age\')

Comment: Great, i fixed my answer too :)